# boto3 not working in TeamCity build step when running in a container build step on a container build agent

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, teamcity, boto3

Our build system uses containerised TeamCity build agents. Some of the build steps use boto3 and to avoid having to customise the base TeamCity build agent image to have boto3, we instead use TeamCity's "Run step within Docker container" feature to specify a python image which has boto3 and a bunch of other python modules installed.

When running the build step, boto3 errors out due to lack of permissions, with errors like:

`botocore.exceptions.ClientError: An error occurred (UnauthorizedOperation) when calling the DescribeInstances operation: You are not authorized to perform this operation.`

The build agent is running in AWS with a "Task Role" which has sufficient permissions, so why does it not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Boto3 will attempt to automatically authenticate using IAM roles set on the container via the ECS task definition, and failing that it will fall back to using the IAM role associated with the EC2 host which is running the container.

You can see which IAM roles are active on each by adding the following commands to a build step:

```
echo "EC2 IAM role"
curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/iam/security-credentials/
echo

echo "AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI = $AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI"
curl http://169.254.170.2$AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI
```

These curl commands pull the current IAM role from the EC2 meta data, and then from the container meta data. The env var `AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI` is set automatically for containers running under ECS.

If you run these commands in a non-containerised build step, it will output the two roles. If you were to run boto3 in the same way, it would prefer the container role if found, and then fallback to the EC2 role.

Now tick the "Run step within Docker container" and specify an arbitrary base image such as `library/python:2.7.15-stretch`.

This time, you will see that the same EC2 IAM role is output, but the `AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI` env var isn't set, and so no container IAM role is found. We wanted the IAM role that had been set on the TeamCity build agent.

In our case, as boto3 didn't find the ECS IAM role, it fell back to the EC2 IAM role, and that role did not have enough privileges to do the boto operations, hence the fail.

**The fix**

The fix is to use the "Additional docker run arguments:" to forward the env var from the TeamCity docker container into the docker container it runs to execute the build step. Edit the build step containing the test commands to have:

`-e AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI=$AWS_CONTAINER_CREDENTIALS_RELATIVE_URI`

Now the build step container will correctly inherit the container IAM role of the build agent container and boto3 will work as expected.